# Updating database records from a form using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel and I am trying to update a grantor's details via a form, however the record in the database table is not registering any changes. I have tried a number of different solutions but unfortunately I've not been successful yet - I have a feeling the issue may involve the update method in the controller not being reached, as when I place a return/redirect statement in the update method this seems to be ignored. The edit method appears to work correctly, however the update method does not alter the database record. I will include snippets of my existing code for clarity. Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated!

**Grantor Controller File**

```
public function update(GrantorRequest $request, $id)
{
    $grantor = Grantor::findOrFail($id);
    $request->validate([
        'grantor_name' => 'required'
    ]);
    $updateDetails = [
        'grantor_name' => $request->get('grantor_name')
    ];
    $grantor->update($updateDetails);
    return redirect()->route('grantors.index');
}
```

Note 'grantor_name' is an example of one field in the database row, there are multiple others which would also require updating.

**Grantors.edit.blade File**

```
<div class="flex-1 px-10">
      <form method="PUT" action="{{ route('grantors.update', $grantor->id) }}" class="is-readonly"> 
        
      @method('PATCH')
      @csrf
      

        <div class="row">
            @if ($errors->any()) <span>{{ $errors }}</span> @endif
         </div>
         <div class="h-auto md:h-96">

            <!-- item -->
            <div x-data=" {isOpen : false} " class="pt-2 pb-4 border-b border-divider">
              <div @click="isOpen = !isOpen"
                class="flex items-center cursor-pointer text-neutral-darker hover:text-primary-hover"
                :class="{'font-bold' : isOpen}">
                <span class="text-xl md:xl">Grantor Details</span>
                <img class="mb-1 duration-300 ml-4 inset-0 h-6 w-6" :class="{'transform rotate-180' : isOpen}"
                    src="../../img/icon-arrow-down.png" alt="missing">
              </div>
              <div x-show.transition.duration.300ms.origin.bottom="isOpen" x-cloak @click.away="isOpen = false"
                class="pt-3 text-sm text-neutral">
                @if($is_editable)
                <div class="flex justify-end">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-edit js-edit"><img class="mb-1 duration-300 ml-4 inset-0 h-6 w-6" src="../../img/edit-icon.svg" alt="edit"></button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-save js-save"><img class="mb-1 duration-300 ml-4 inset-0 h-6 w-6" src="../../img/save-icon.svg" alt="save"></button>
                </div>
                @endif
                <form class="w-full max-w-sm">
                  <div class="md:flex md:items-center mb-6 ml-6">
                    <div class="md:w-1/7">
                      <label  for="grantor_name" class="block text-neutral-darker font-bold md:text-right mb-1 md:mb-0 pr-4 " for="inline-full-name" disabled>Grantor/ Company/ Organisation Name *
                      </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="md:w-1/6">
                      <input class="bg-gray-200 appearance-none border-2 border-gray-200 rounded w-full py-2 px-4 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-green-900 is-disabled @error('grantor_name') is-invalid @enderror" name="grantor_name" value="{{ old('grantor_name') ?? $grantor->grantor_name }}" id="grantor_name" type="text" disabled >
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

**Tenant Routes File**

```
Route::get('/grantors/{id}/edit', [App\Http\Controllers\GrantorController::class, 'edit'])->name('grantors.edit');
Route::put('/grantors', [App\Http\Controllers\GrantorController::class, 'update'])->name('grantors.update');
```

**Grantor Model**

```
protected $fillable= [
    'grantor_name'
]);
```

Note that there are many other fields included in the $fillable which I have not included for purposes of length.

Comment: You're grabbing the model, validating the input, and creating an array, but you never actually attempt to update the model.

Comment: Thank you for commenting, would you be able to elaborate on how I would update the model correctly in this instance?

Comment: is `GrantorRequest` a `FormRequest`?  also the method is `$request->input(....)` to get the inputs from the Request ... it is super rare that you would actually want to call `get`, Laravel added the `input` method for very particular reasons

Comment: I believe it is a `FormRequest`, I have replaced each of the `get`s with `input` in the syntax of `'grantor_name' => $request->input('grantor_name')` but no difference has been made unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Because you're not actually updating the model. You need to call `update` on your model:

```php
    public function update(GrantorRequest $request, $id)
    {
        // Dont do `toArray` . You'll lose the Eloquent model. 
        $grantor = Grantor::findOrFail($id);
        $request->validate([
            'grantor_name' => 'required'
        ]);
        $updateDetails = [
            'grantor_name' => $request->get('grantor_name')
        ];
        // Notice the call below
        $grantor->update($updateDetails);

        return redirect()->route('grantors.index');
    }
```

The route definition should be changed as well:

```php
// `id` param was missing
 Route::patch('/grantors/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\GrantorController::class, 'update'])->name('grantors.update');
```

And html forms do not support `patch` or `put` method. You should do it like below:

```
 <form method="POST" action="{{ route('grantors.update', $grantor->id) }}" class="is-readonly"> 
        
      @method('PATCH')
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I made those amendments to the code but unfortunately the database table still isn't registering any changes

Comment: I updated my answer. Double check your `$fillable` in Grantor::class.

Comment: Thanks, yes I've checked the Grantor model too and all of the desired fields are in the $fillable

Comment: No problem. Then I would say make sure the controller is really hit. 
Put a `dd($grantor->toArray())` after the model update line and let me know the output.

Comment: When I include the `dd($grantor->toArray())` there is no different output, I am still directed to the /grantors page specified in the tenant file with no update to the database record

Comment: Oh I see now. Your route definition is incorrect. It's not taking the `{id}` parameter into account. I will update my answer.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate your reply, unfortunately when making those changes the error message 'The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE.' is returned

Answer (score 0):

1. Change your `Grantors.edit.blade.php` File:

```php
<div class="flex-1 px-10">
      <form method="POST" action="{{ route('grantors.update', ['id' => $grantor->id]) }}" class="is-readonly"> 
        
      @method('PUT')
      @csrf
// ...
```

Notice the changes:

1a) `method="PUT"` to `method="POST"`

1b) `@method('PATCH')` to `@method('PUT')`

1c) `{{ route('grantors.update', $grantor->id) }}` to `{{ route('grantors.update', ['id' => $grantor->id]) }}`

``

2. Change the *Tenant Routes File*

```php
// ...
Route::put('/grantors/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\GrantorController::class, 'update'])->name('grantors.update');
// ...
```

2a) Included the `/{id}` segment in the route.

3. Make sure you have one `<form>` tag in your `Grantors.edit.blade.php` file.

From the looks of it, you have 2 `<form>` tags. One nested inside another.

`<form method="PUT" action="{{ route('grantors.update', $grantor->id) }}" class="is-readonly">`

and

`<form class="w-full max-w-sm">`

4. Clear route cache if cached previously.

*In your terminal, run the command below:*

`php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but when I made these changes the error 'The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE.' is returned

Comment: @ConlaodhQuinn , Instead of `@method('PUT')` try this: `{{ method_field('PUT') }}`

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately after doing that, the same 'The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE.' error is returned

Comment: @ConlaodhQuinn ,  Okay. Could you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70623962/edit) and paste the request body that is submitted by the form?

Comment: Apologies I am not sure what you mean by request body, which file would you like me to share?

Comment: @ConlaodhQuinn ,  I would like the see the *form data* that is submitted to the server. You can see it from the *Network* tab of the browser console when you submit your HTML form.

Comment: @ConlaodhQuinn , In addition, try replacing `{{ route('grantors.update', $grantor->id) }}` with  `{{ route('grantors.update', ['id' => $grantor->id]) }}` to see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in getting back to you, I have implemented your suggestions but have had no luck fixing the issue yet - when I submit the HTML form the network tab displays a 419: unknown status error. I have a feeling that the update method call is not being reached at all, if you were free for a chat I would greatly appreciate any insight to the problem you may have!

Comment: @ConlaodhQuinn ,  We could discuss this more in chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240929/updating-database-records-from-a-form-using-laravel

Comment: Unfortunately as I am a new user to Stack Overflow I don't have access to the chat function yet - would you have any suggestions for how else I could contact you? Thank you

Comment: @ConlaodhQuinn ,  contact@stevenmwesigwa.com

Comment: Thank you I will message you directly through this address!

Comment: I have sent you an email directly to contact@stevenmwesigwa.com, please feel free to have a look at this when you get the chance - thank you